# Boost: wrong number of template arguments

Tags: c++, boost

I'm pretty new to c++ and boost library: 
Not sure what I'm doing wrong in the following code:
I'm following the example found here http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppBoostGraphExample4.htm

```
 typedef boost::adjacency_list
  <
    //Store all edges as a std::vector
    boost::vecS,
    //Store all vertices in a std::vector
    boost::vecS,
    //Relations are both ways (in this example)
    //(note: but you can freely change it to boost::directedS)
    boost::undirectedS,
    //All vertices are person names of type std::string
    boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t,std::string>,
    //All edges are weights equal to the encounter frequencies
    boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t,double>,
    //Graph itself has a std::string name
    boost::property<boost::graph_name_t,std::string>
 > Graph;
```

When I try to compile the code I get

**error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/usr/include/boost/pending/property.hpp:22 error: provided for 'tempate struct boost::property'**

In my code the error is pointing to this line:

```
boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t,double>
```

I'm using version 1.55 of the library

Comment: i count 7 template parameters in `boost::adjacency_list` but you provided 6. think you may miss `EdgeList`

Comment: I still get same error providing an additional argument `listS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be including the wrong version of the header. If you check the path to `property.hpp` it doesn't find a path in the `boost_1_55_0` subtree.

It compiles as is on my Ubuntu box with Boost 1_55